# Doubt in Probability question

Tags: probability

**Question:**

> A, B are two inaccurate arithmeticians whose chances of solving a given question correctly are $\frac{1}{8}$ and $\frac{1}{12}$ respectively. They solve a problem and obtained the same result. If it is 1000 to 1 against their making the same mistake, find the chance that the result is correct?

This is a question which I did in my class. I have a doubt when my teacher found the probability of both giving the same wrong answer (or same mistake). My teacher wrote it as $\frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{11}{12}\cdot\frac{1}{1001}$. What I understood is that this term means that: the probability of both making the same mistake given that they both give a wrong answer is $\frac{1}{1001}$, **and not** directly the probability of both making the same mistake is $1/1001$.

Am I right in thinking so?

Comment: Yes, you are right. $\frac{1}{1001}$ is the probability of making the same mistake conditional on both being mistaken.

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera thank you.